# Can I make a DAX measure to count households lost based on non-contract renewal and service category?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, measure

I'm back again. This time I am having trouble as per the question.

Before I layout the problem, here are the layout of the tables I am working with:

- Household Table:

| HouseholdID | Name | OwnerID | OwnerName | StateCodeName | Service Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | Smith, Sam | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Active | Platinum |
| HG78G-KJS00-HB524 | Capaldi, Lewis | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Active | D |
| JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | Spears, Britney | C20R2-991MN-LOP93 | Chris R | Active | B |
| GJ5V6-BBNS8-992NS | Black, William | C20R2-991MN-LOP94 | Chris R | Inactive | C |
| NNBS2-GJS6T-578TF | Swift, Taylor | C20R2-991MN-LOP95 | Chris R | Inactive | A |

- Service Period Table:

| serviceperiodID | OwnerID | OwnerName | statecodename | Startdate | Enddate | Serviceperiodname | HouseholdID | totalfee | totalfee x gst | Current Stage Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AD123-15GAT-OPSSS | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Inactive | 25/01/2023 | 24/01/2024 | Smith, Sam - 25/1/2023 to 24/1/2024 | LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | $5,500 | $5,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |
| HSB94-875JG-6G8GD | C20R2-991MN-LOP92 | Chris R | Active | 25/01/2024 | 25/01/2025 | Smith, Sam - 25/1/2024 to 24/1/2025 | LOIF7-JGN25-453JG | $11,000 | $10,000.00 | Service Period Active |
| HG049-Y78JF-LAK25 | C20R2-991MN-LOP93 | Chris R | Active | 14/06/2023 | 13/06/2024 | Spears, Britney - 14/6/2023 to 13/6/2024 | JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | $3,300 | $3,000.00 | Service Period Active |
| NAUS5-JS94B-VT6R7 | C20R2-991MN-LOP94 | Chris R | Inactive | 20/04/2022 | 19/04/2023 | Spears, Britney - 20/4/2022 to 19/4/2023 | JJK83-IOP0S-MG674 | $2,200 | $2,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |
| BHY24-HGF24-JGN51 | C20R2-991MN-LOP95 | Chris R | Inactive | 5/01/2023 | 4/01/2024 | Swift, Taylor - 5/1/2023 to 4/1/2024 | NNBS2-GJS6T-578TF | $5,500 | $5,000.00 | Service Period Inactive |
| NS836-JG98T-287JF | C20R2-991MN-LOP96 | Chris R | Inactive | 6/06/2022 | 5/06/2023 | Black, William - 6/6/2022 to 5/6/2023 | GJ5V6-BBNS8-992NS | $2,000 | $1,818.18 | Service Period Inactive |
| LLSK0-002G8-JJJGS | C20R2-991MN-LOP96 | Chris R | Inactive | 3/01/2023 | 2/01/2024 | Capaldi, Lewis - 3/1/2023 to 2/1/2024 | HG78G-KJS00-HB524 | $880 | $800.00 | Service Period Inactive |

The tables are in a one-to-many relationship with the HouseholdID columns.

I am trying to calculate how many households I have lost from last year. When I say a lost household, I mean that the household no longer has any active contracts (or service period) with us as they did not renew from last year's contract. There are 2 ways for these clients to exist in the database. Their household is considered "Inactive" under the 'Household'[statecodename] column, or they are tagged as a "D" in the 'Household'[ServiceCategory] column. Being tagged as Service Category 'D' means we are performing other services for them outside of the contracts.

So using the example tables above, and going from todays date the 7th of Feb 24, the counter should equal 2 as we have lost Taylor Swift (Household inactive and did not renew this year) and Lewis Capaldi (Household tagged "D" and did not renew this year). If we were to reach later in the year and Britney Spears did not renew the contract, then the counter would go to 3 after we get past the end date of that contract/service period as the household would be tagged as inactive if no other services were occurring.

I have tried a few different measures, but keep getting a large number back, when I know realistically the number should be 0 as all clients have renewed their contract so far this year.

```
Households Lost_ = 
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(TODAY())
VAR EndOfYear_ = DATE(CurrentYear, 12, 31)
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(SUMMARIZE('Merged - Service Period', 'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid])),
        FILTER(
            'Merged - Service Period',
            'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_enddate] <= EndOfYear_ &&
            'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_enddate] > date(2022, 12, 31) &&
            'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_enddate] < TODAY()
        )
    )
```

If anyone could give me some DAX code to help me out with this, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you only need it for current year? or all year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Households Lost = 
  var households = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Merged - Service Period',
      [finpal_householdid],
      "endDate",
        CALCULATE(
          MAX([finpal_enddate]),
          ALLEXCEPT('Merged - Service Period', 'Merged - Service Period'[finpal_householdid])
        )
    )
  return
    COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
        households,
        YEAR([endDate]) = YEAR(TODAY()) && [endDate] <= TODAY()
      )
    )
```